# Delete cache on a dynamic page in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, caching

I have reviewed the documentation of CI regarding caching a full page here:
https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/caching.html

I understand that I can cache a controller/function using the below; anywhere inside that function:

```
$this->output->cache($n);
```

However my problem is that for example we have a page:

article/specific/this-is-a-slug

as you can see the

- controller->article
- function->specific
- slug->this-is-a-slug

When I cache the function inside itself, the system automatically detects that slug and creates a new cache for each slug uniquely.

However when I want to delete the cache for that specific slug I do not know how I can do it outside the function itself:

```
$this->output->delete_cache('/foo/bar');
```

How can specific that I need only the cache for this specific slug to be deleted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it wherever you wish, as long as you know the URI. The string in the `delete_cache` is the URI.

`$this->output->delete_cache('/article/specific/this-is-a-slug');`

> Caching can be enabled on a per-page basis, and you can set the length of time that a page should remain cached before being refreshed.